# How can I implement security in spring restful?

Tags: spring, extjs, spring-security, restful-architecture

I'm developing an web application using [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0) in client side and [spring](http://spring.io) RESTFUL in server side.

My server application is **RESTFUL**. I don't have even one page in spring application.

Client send an AJAX request to server and then server response it. I want to Add **Authentication** and **Authorization** to my application. When user open the web application(Extjs page), it send an Ajax request to see can it go to dashboard page or not? Server only get `true` or `false`. If server return `true`, Extjs can request data user. but if server return `false` it go to login page. In login page user enter `username` and `password` and then click on login button and then send an ajax request to login.

In server side, Every request received, it check if user login before, return suitable response, Otherwise it return 405 error.

How can I implement this with **spring security**?

**Note**:
I don't want to use basic authentication. I want to create an login form with Extjs and then send an Ajax request for **Authentication**.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the basic knowledge of Spring Security.

A typical web application using Spring security, it authenticates the user and depending on the result it decides whether to send secured page (if successful) or to send login page (if unsuccessful).

But in this case, i.e. in REST application, the responses are typically in JSON format. So we cannot send views/page back to client. We need to send JSON.

What you can do is override and implement your own custom Authentication Handlers and Authentication Entry point. Here in these custom handlers, you can send your custom JSON response to client.

You can implement following interfaces:

- **AuthenticationEntryPoint:** Called when authentication fails. Returns `401 UNAUTHORIZED` status.
- **AuthenticationSuccessHandler:** You can handle your successfull authentication response in `onAuthenticationSuccess` method.
- **AuthenticationFailureHandler:** As the name says, it used for handling Authentication failure. Use `onAuthenticationFailure` method to custimize your failure response.
- **LogoutSuccessHandler:** Use `onLogoutSuccess` method to customize your logout behaviour.

Examples:
[Secure REST Services Using Spring Security](https://dzone.com/articles/secure-rest-services-using)
[AuthenticationFailureHandler](http://progrnotes.blogspot.in/2012/07/spring-security-authenification-failure.html)
[AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://www.jcombat.com/spring/custom-authentication-success-handler-with-spring-security)

You can check [this](https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/stateless-spring-security-on-rest-api/) link for implementing Stateless Spring security authentication

Comment: @morteza malvandi Show us what have you done till now, like code snippet or something. Maybe that can help.